# How does a country with lesser exports than imports get the foreign exchange to fund the excess?

Tags: foreign-exchange, balance-of-trade, balance-of-payments

Let's take a developing country.

Assume it's exports, tourism revenue, repatriation by workers working abroad all totally contribute 100$ of forex for the country per year.

And it's imports are 110$.

How does the country get the excess 10$ of forex needed every year?

Their own currency may be too weak to be used for purchasing dollars. So is selling gold the only option. I assume there are a lot of countries whose imports are higher than exports - how do they manage this?

My assumption that they are unable buy forex from the forex market inspite of having enough local currency is because of stories like these

- [IMF warns Bangladesh of depleting forex reserves](https://www.dhakatribune.com/business/2023/05/07/imf-warns-of-depleting-forex-reserves)

From this IMF warning, it seems as if Bangladesh is not having a problem of having money but having a problem of not having forex.

Comment: How can a currency be too weak to be used to purchase dollar? Would you have an example?

Comment: @Alex - I am looking at Sri Lanka a while back. I had read that they couldn't pay for crude oil imports because they didn't have dollars. I had assumed that if they could have purchased dollars, they would have.

Comment: obviously they get \$10 from somewhere. Maybe they already had savings, maybe they buy it on the forex market (causing the value of whatever they bought it with to go down), maybe they borrowed it. All of the usual ways that you can get \$10 still 
apply in this case. Also it is probably not the country that does this, but someone who lives in the country.

Comment: If you read someone cannot pay for imports, it literally means they do not import anymore.

Comment: @user253751 - Sri Lanka actually couldn't import fertilizer because they had a forex problem, a balance of payment problem - https://www.omfif.org/2022/07/sri-lanka-crisis-shows-why-reserves-matter/

Comment: @user93353 that is another way of saying nobody wanted to sell them dollars. "Balance of payments" is another way of interpreting the problem, an academic, ivory-tower way; the actual problem is that nobody would give them \$10.

Comment: @AKdemy - they don't import because they have a forex reserve crisis - for e.g.  Bangladesh is one of the fast growing economies but they are having a forex problem - https://www.dhakatribune.com/business/2023/05/07/imf-warns-of-depleting-forex-reserves

Comment: Like if you never take your car to the mechanic and eventually it stops working because the head gasket is blown, you take it to the mechanic and he says "the head gasket is blown" but the article someone writes about you might say you "skipped preventative maintenance". Which one is actually the problem? Did the car stop because the head gasket blew or did the car stop because you skipped preventative maintenance?

Comment: So what exactly is your question in this case? If they don't import because they cannot pay for it, there is no funding available for it.

Comment: @AKdemy - if it only depends on funding & not on forex, then why is IMF warning Bangladesh about depleting forex reserves - https://www.dhakatribune.com/business/2023/05/07/imf-warns-of-depleting-forex-reserves? Why do reserves matter at all if they can buy it from the market as long as they have local funds?